# Javascript match string contains bracket

Tags: javascript

I have string which contains bracket, and I want to match it, I tried below code but does not work

Example

```
let testString = "My First Name is (Ahmed), and Last Name is (Ali)";
let result = testString.match("My First Name is (Ahmed)");
consol.log(result);
```

the result is null

Answer (score 2):

`.match()` treats the argument as a regular expression, and brackets have special meaning in regular expressions.

If you're matching a fixed string rather than a regular expression, use `.includes()`.

```js
let testString = "My First Name is (Ahmed), and Last Name is (Ali)";
let result = testString.includes("My First Name is (Ahmed)");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I have variable contains string may be with bracket or no need to check like below example how can achieve that let result = testString.match(matchString); and matchString = "My First Name is (Ahmed)" or may matchString = "My First Name is Ahmed"

Comment: I've updated the answer. Just use `.includes()` instead of `.match()`.